# Return -1 if JSON Array is NULL works only in some data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I wanted to:

- Return `-1` if `data`(array) is null or empty
- If data is not null and if the array has `rain_value` property I wanted to get the 2nd index value of that array based on its length

Below is the snippet of my code:

```
success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
    $.map(data, function (e) {
        var max = -1;
        var dev_id = e.dev_id;
        var data = e.data;
        var r;
        if (data) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                r = parseFloat(data[j].rain_value) || 0;
                arr[j] = parseFloat(r);
            }
        }
        if (arr.length) {
            max = arr[1] * 4;
            //max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) * 4;
        }

        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            var jsonObj_device_id = jsonObj.features[k].properties.device_id;
            if (jsonObj_device_id == dev_id) {
                var nameR = "rain_intensity";
                var rainValue = max;
                jsonObj.features[k].properties[nameR] = rainValue;
            }
        }
        console.log(dev_id + " " + max)
    });
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why it works only in some data.
Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skh2L6as/12/). Thanks!

Comment: Are you making sure that `arr` is empty before adding any new data?  Add `arr = [];` after `var r;` and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: If you look at the Fiddle, I want to assign `max` value to `-1` if the `data` is null or empty.

Comment: Yes, and you're not clearing the array before each iteration, so it has values every time, after the first time there is data, and therefore has length.  http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/skh2L6as/15/

Comment: Works! You should put your comment in answer for me to accept it!  Thanks!

Comment: Lol - I was just doing that.  Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning an empty array value to the variable `arr` outside your loop, but not within the loop.  This means that as soon as you have data and that array is populated every following iteration will have array values.  You need to clear it every time, or only declare it in the loop...

```
success: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
    $.map(data, function (e) {
        var max = -1;
        var dev_id = e.dev_id;
        var data = e.data;
        var r;
        arr = [];   // <---- clear the array here
        if (data) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                r = parseFloat(data[j].rain_value) || 0;
                arr[j] = parseFloat(r);
            }
        }
        if (arr.length) {
            max = arr[1] * 4;
            //max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr) * 4;
        }

        for (var k = 0; k < len; k++) {
            var jsonObj_device_id = jsonObj.features[k].properties.device_id;
            if (jsonObj_device_id == dev_id) {
                var nameR = "rain_intensity";
                var rainValue = max;
                jsonObj.features[k].properties[nameR] = rainValue;
            }
        }
        console.log(dev_id + " " + max)
    });
}
```

**[Working jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/skh2L6as/15/)**